# How to unwrap tag from a BeautifulSoup Tag object?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a BeautifulSoup Tag object which looks like this

```
<p>This is an example of something that I'm <strong>confused</strong> about</p>
```

I'd like to obtain

```
This is an example of something that I'm <strong>confused</strong> about
```

It seems like this should be an easy application of something like .unwrap() in BeautifulSoup, but each thing I try doesn't work. Could I get a hand here?

Comment: Try `p.text`   ..

Comment: `.text` would strip out `<strong>` though, no?

Comment: how about - `" ".join([str(e) for e in  tag_data.children])` here tag_data would be `tag_data=soup.find("p")`

Comment: @gammapoint, indeed you're right, I suggested before testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> something like .unwrap() in BeautifulSoup, but each thing I try
> doesn't work

`unwrap()` modifies the `soup` object itself, to see the result, print the `soup`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
soup.find("p").unwrap()

print(soup)
```

Output:

```
This is an example of something that I'm <strong>confused</strong> about
```

Comment: That does work, thanks! Thought it might be easier than creating a soup object from the `Tag`, but maybe that's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the .renderContents() method:

```
text = soup.find('p').renderContents()
```

Comment: What I don't get about this (and is probably why I'm having trouble with the other method) is that the result of soup.find('p') is `None` and so this doesn't work.

Comment: Please add your full code to your question.